# Find the the value of one field that matches the maximum value of data in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, aggregate

I'm trying to write a query that gets the value of one field that's associated with the *maximum value* of another field (or fields).  Let's say I have the following table of data:

```
OrderID CustomerID  OrderDate   LocationID          
1       4           1/1/2001    1001
2       4           1/2/2001    1003
3       4           1/3/2001    1001
4       5           1/4/2001    1001
5       5           1/5/2001    1001
6       5           1/6/2001    1003
7       5           1/7/2001    1002
8       5           1/8/2001    1003
9       5           1/8/2001    1002
```

Grouping by `CustomerID`, I want to get the maximum `OrderDate` and then the `LocationID` associated with whatever is the maximum `OrderDate`.  If there are several records that share the maximum order date, then take the `LocationID` associated with the maximum `OrderID` from among those records with the maximum date.

The final set of data should look like this:

```
CustomerID  OrderDate   LocationID      
4           1/3/2001    1001
5           1/8/2001    1002
```

I had been trying to write a query with lots of nested subqueries and ugly joins, but I'm not really getting anywhere.  What SQL do I need to write to help me get this result.

Answer (score 5):

```
with cte As
(
select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by CustomerID 
                           order by OrderDate desc, OrderId desc) as rn
from yourtable
)
select CustomerID, OrderDate,LocationID
from cte 
where rn=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
   C.Name,
   C.CustomerID,
   X.*
FROM
   Customers C
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 OrderDate, LocationID
      FROM Orders O
      WHERE C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
      ORDER BY OrderDate Desc, OrderID Desc
   ) X
```

If you will pull any columns from the Customers table, this will probably **outperform other methods**.

If not, then the `Row_Number` answer, pulling only from Orders, will probably be best. But if you restrict by Customer in any way, then the `CROSS APPLY` will again be best. Possibly by a big margin.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a subquery as a value, not as a join:

```
select customerId,orderDate,locationId
  from orders o1
 where orderDate = (
           select top 1 orderdate
             from orders o2
            where o1.customerId = o2.customerId
            order by orderdate desc
       )
```